# How to run a S3 backed private docker registry in kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, docker-registry

I have a private AWS S3 backed docker registry running in a container on a fedora 21 host.  I'm trying to move that setup into kubernetes.

My configs,

registry-service.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1beta3
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    name: registry
  name: registry
spec:
  ports:
  - name: registry
    port: 5000
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 5000
  selector:
    name: registry
```

registry-controller.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1beta3
kind: ReplicationController
metadata:
  labels:
    name: registry
  name: registry
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    name: registry
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        name: registry
    spec:
      containers:
        -
          env:
            -
              name: SETTINGS_FLAVOR
              value: s3
            -
              name: AWS_BUCKET
              value: docker-registry
            -
              name: STORAGE_PATH
              value: /registry
            -
              name: AWS_KEY
              value: XXXXXXXXXXXXX
            -
              name: AWS_SECRET
              value: XXXXXXXXXXXXXX
            -
              name: SEARCH_BACKEND
              value: sqlalchemy
          image: registry
          name: registry
          ports:
            -
              containerPort: 5000
              protocol: TCP
```

Then running,

```
kubectl.sh create -f registry-service.yaml
services/registry

kubectl.sh create -f registry-controller.yaml
replicationcontrollers/registry
```

kubectl.sh get pods

```
NAME                                                                   READY     REASON    RESTARTS   AGE         2d
registry-83icn                                                         0/1       Running   13         7m
```

checking the logs it looks like a DNS issue,  I'm not sure where to proceed from here.

```
kubectl logs registry-83icn

Error: 'tcp://10.0.173.63:5000' is not a valid port number.
```

What am I missing here?  Do I need to configure DNS somewhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your registry container is in a crash loop. I think the problem is that we automatically inject environment variables of the form ${SERVICE_NAME}_HOST to emulate Docker links variables.  The registry looks for an environment variable named REGISTRY_HOST.  Since your kubernetes service is named 'registry' there is a name conflict.

If you rename your registry Service to something like 'private_registry' then I think it will work correctly.

Comment: That was it!  Thanks very much.  New error to deal with now, Permission denied: './registry._setup_database.lock'